# Reduce Kubernetes Cluster costs at night

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Google's Kubernetes Engine to manage a cluster with several node pools. Each pool has different configurations (ex. not all have auto-scaling).

The pools are mostly unused during the night, and so I would like to reduce resource consumption and cost during this period (about 10 hours).

I've considered stopping VM instances at the end of the day and restarting them in the morning. Additionally I could temporarily scale down the number of nodes by running  `gcloud container clusters resize $CLUSTER_NAME --size=0`

What would be the best option to reduce costs during unused periods? Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you considered another, maybe in the Free Tier, instance, that runs this command periodically with a cron job? As a solution if there is no other alternative in GKE.

Comment: Since you have auto-scaling disabled,  easy possible way would be to reduce the node size that you are already doing. Automating such task may run in to another issue as discussed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/42649).

Comment: Stopping GCE VM instances won't work. GKE will restart, or replace them with new ones. I suggest resizing node pools to 0, or using Cluster Autoscaler (but it won't be scaling down to 0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using cluster autoscaler (which adjusts number of nodes in your node pools) will not be able to scale all your node pools to zero. This is because there are some system pods running in your cluster (`kubectl get pods -n kube-system`).

You can however, force scaling down of node pools to zero as you pointed out, with a script calling:

```
gcloud container clusters resize $CLUSTER --num-nodes=0 [--node-pool=$POOL]
```